# Filter by children and return parent plus children in a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like the one below and I'm looking to get the parent (Dashboard) and the name of its child when searching for 'Summary'

```
[
  {
     Dashboard1: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'SomeThingElse'},
       {name: 'SomeThingElse2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard2: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'Different'},
       {name: 'Different2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard3: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard4: [
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent2'}
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent3'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent4'},
     ]
  }
]
```

I have an input that searches for 'Summary' and I want it to return just

```
[
  {
    Dashboard1: [
      {name: 'Summary'},
    ]
  },
  {
    Dashboard2: [
      {name: 'Summary'},
    ]
  },
  {
    Dashboard2: [
      {name: 'Summary'},
    ]
  }
]
```

I have this function that filters Dashboard4 where Summary is not present as a child but returns all children as well.

```
function filterByValue(array, value) {
    return array.filter((data) =>  JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const a = [
  {
     Dashboard1: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'SomeThingElse'},
       {name: 'SomeThingElse2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard2: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'Different'},
       {name: 'Different2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard3: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard4: [
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent2'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent3'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent4'},
     ]
  }
];

function filterByValue(array, value) {
    const result = [];
    array.forEach(e => {
        const keys = Object.keys(e);
        const obj = {};
        keys.forEach(k => {
            const matches = e[k].filter(i => i.name === value);
            if (matches.length > 0) {
                obj[k] = matches;
            }
        });
        if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0) {
            result.push(obj);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(filterByValue(a, 'Summary'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the array, you can use a more coincise function like that:

```
    const array = [
  {
     Dashboard1: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'SomeThingElse'},
       {name: 'SomeThingElse2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard2: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'Different'},
       {name: 'Different2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard3: [
       {name: 'Summary'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent2'}
     ]
  },
  {
     Dashboard4: [
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent2'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent3'},
       {name: 'AnotherDifferent4'},
     ]
  }]

const filterByValue = (array, value) => array.filter(el => {
    const objValues = Object.values(el).flat()
    const elementsValues = objValues.map(v => Object.values(v)).flat()
    return elementsValues.some(v => v.includes(value))
})

console.log(filterByValue(array, 'Summary'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reusable function for a similar scenario.

```
  const searchNestedArraySearch = (val, arr, key, childKey) => {
  const newArr = arr.map((e, i) => {

    //Get the propert need from nested object via the key and appending the index
    let firstChildObj = e[`${key}${i + 1}`];

    console.log(firstChildObj);

    // loop through the nested property array
    const checkProperty = firstChildObj.map((e) => {
      const valueProp = e[childKey] === val ? true : false;

      if (valueProp) {
        return { [childKey]: val };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });

    // remove null value from each array to get specified search
    const filterEmpty = checkProperty.filter((val) => val !== null);

    // return array of property containing search value
    if (filterEmpty.length) {
      return { [`${key}${i + 1}`]: filterEmpty };
    }
  });

  return newArr.filter((e) => e !== undefined);
};

console.log(searchNestedArray("Summary", data, "Dashboard", "name"));

/**
 * Filter value from nested object
 * @param {String} val 
 * @param {Array} arr 
 * @param {string} key 
 * @param {String} childKey 
 */
```